# I cannot remove apache2. /var/www dir is still there. I can still start apache service

Tags: apache-2.2, remove

I have failed to remove apache2 from my ubuntu server.

I did `$ sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2` and `$ sudo apt-get remove apache2` and `$ sudo apt-get autoremove` and when I tried to do `$ sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2-utils` I get dependency error.

After I did the above steps I could still do `$ sudo service apache2 restart`. The server restarts as normal. The www dir is still there intact. This tells me that apache2 was not removed.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: /var/www will not be removed with removing apache, because its not part of instalation only directory with your site.
If you tried apt-get remove and apache still starting then maybe it wasnt installed with apt but compiled from source

Comment: try execute `dpkg --get-selections | grep apache` and show output

Answer (score 1):

You can always avoid `*-common` and `*-bin` inflation by running `apt-get --purge remove apache2*`

Answer (score 0):

The `apache2` package isn't the web server at all; it only contains a few files:

```
/usr/share/bug/apache2/control
/usr/share/bug/apache2/script
/usr/share/doc/apache2
```

If the autoremove didn't do it, then get rid of `apache2.2-common`, `apache2.2-bin`, and `apache2-mpm-_____` for whichever MPM you're using.  And even that is not going to delete your `/var/www` directory.

Comment: How can I find what I should append to apache2-mpm- ?

Comment: @MariusJonsson As B14D3 said, check your current selections to find installed packages to remove.